# Start service from Activity or Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service

I have a MainActivity which holds two fragments `Fragment1` and `Fragment2`. Each fragment has its own service `Service1` for `Fragment1` and `Service2`for the other.

I would like to know which approach is the best for starting service:

1. Start a service from its fragment .
2. Manage all `startService()` and `stopService()` calls from the MainActivity.

Comment: You can choose which one you want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've mentioned that each fragment has its own service, logically the best and clean solution is to bind each service to its own fragment's lifecycle.

But otherwise, there's nothing wrong if you bind both of them with the parent activity as the lifecycles of both the fragments are implicitly bound to the lifecycle of the parent activity i.e. MainActivity. Its totally up to you to decide.